# Applying for Indefinite Leave to Remain on Tier 2 visa requirement - do the 5 years of working need to be continous?

Tags: visas, uk, work, long-term

I understand that you must work for 5 years in the UK to be granted ILR, however if for example, you work for 2 years in the UK on tier 2 and then switch to do tier 4 for 1 year in the UK to study a masters and then switch back to tier 2 to work for another 3 years, will that classify as being employed for 5 years or do the 5 years need to be continuous? Just to be clear, you would remain in the UK the whole time.